# Should a range for loop be used instead of iterators on a vector?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, iterator

Given a vector, `vc,` one can iterate through the vector with a range for:

```
for (auto c : vc)
    std::cout << c;
```

Or with an iterator:

```
for (auto it = vc.cbegin(); it != vc.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;
```

Is there a functional reason to use one method over the other, or is this merely a matter of style?

Comment: note that with your use of `auto` in the range-based for-loop you're getting a *copy* of your vector elements, which, if your object is expensive to copy, may yield unwanted performance issues. With the use of iterators you get back a const reference, so the copies don't happen here. A way to get back a const reference in the range-based for is `for (const auto& c : vc) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the performance point of view there isn't really a difference. As Bjarne Stroustrup writes in his book the C++ Programming language 4th edition:

> The simplest loop is a range- for -statement; it simply gives the programmer access to each element
>   of a range.

As a fan of the KISS principle I tend to prefer simpler constructs over more complex ones. However, it really boils down to what you want to achieve. From the same book Bjarne reveals why a range-for loop is designed to be simple:

> Note that a range- for loop is a deliberately simple construct. For
>   example, using it you can’t touch two elements at the same time and
>   can’t effectively traverse two ranges simultaneously. For that we need
>   a general for-statement.

Consequently, there are contexts that you can't use a range-for loop and you have to reside to the classical for-statement.

Bottom line use range-for loop when ever possible because is simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 4):

It is more or less a matter of style, but consider it this way; range-for loops are more concise than explicit iterator usage.  The less code you write, the less places where things can go wrong.

Comment: Also, it's a whole lot more readable, as it hides the implementation details of the loop.

Comment: Range for may also be clearer to compilers, improving optimizability.

Answer (score 3):

There are two substantive differences between your two examples. First, `auto c` creates a copy of each element, so use `auto const& c` if you don't want to create unnecessary copies. Second, range `for` is implemented in terms of non-const iterators, but your `for` loop uses const iterators. That doesn't matter if `vc` is a standard container, but some containers (e.g. those in Qt) implement copy-on-write semantics using an internal shared pointer, in which case the use of non-const iterators will unnecessarily copy the entire container. You can avoid this and still use the nice range `for` syntax by using C++17 `std::as_const`:

```
for (auto const& c : std::as_const(vc))
    std::cout << c;
```

You can easily implement your own version of `as_const` if your environment doesn't provide it.

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example, they are equivalent. And since they are equivalent, you naturally want to prefer the shortest version which happens to also be the least error-prone -- for free.

The range-for loop was also proposed to be shortened furthermore to:

```
for ( var : range )
```

where `var` would have type `auto&&` (aka forwading/universal reference), which is the best way to take a reference to an object. Just `auto var` will make a copy of each element, which might not be cheap. Unfortunately, it did not pass.

You typically don't work with iterators directly so range-for you should be your first choice. Explicit iterators may also point to out-of-range elements since you can freely move in the range, leading to undefined behavior.